# having problem with cookie and jwt authentication

Tags: express, cookies, jwt

My server in express sends a Cookie with accesstoken and refreshtoken when user is successfully logged in.  I redirect him to /user  and in user I am unable to send cookie to jwt middleware. In storage there are no cookie

This is my backend code :

```
    const loggedInUser = await User.findById(user._id).select("-password -refreshToken")
    //cookies by default can be edited but with httponly it can only be modified by server
    const option = {
        httpOnly : true,
        // secure : true,
    }

     return res.status(200)
     .cookie("accessToken",accessToken,option)
     .cookie("refreshToken" , refreshToken,option)
     .json(
        new ApiResponse(200,{
            user : loggedInUser , accessToken , refreshToken

        },
        "user logged in successful")
     )
})
```

this is my frontend login code:

```
    const handleSubmit = async(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    try{
         
         
        //  console.log(userlogin);

        //  const res = await login(userlogin)

        const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/user/login',         userlogin);

        
        const accessToken = response.data.data.accessToken
        console.log(accessToken)
        const refreshToken = response.data.data.refreshToken
        const name = response.data.data.user.fullName
        const userid = response.data.data.user._id
        console.log("this is username:",name);
        let expires = new Date()
        expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + (1 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
       
        console.log("user LoggedIn" , response.data);

        if(response.status ==200) { 
            window.localStorage.setItem("token" , accessToken)
            window.localStorage.setItem("loggedIn" , true)
            window.localStorage.setItem("username",name)
            window.localStorage.setItem("userID", userid)
            window.location.href="/user"
            
            

        }

    }
    catch(error){
        console.log("login failed in login.jsx" , error);
    }
    }
```

this is my /user code:

```
function UserProfile() {
  const token = window.localStorage.getItem("token")
  const _id = window.localStorage.getItem("userID")


  // problem in fetching data
  const fetchData = async()=>{
    try{ 
  const config = {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    }
};
  
     const response  =  await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/v1/user/userId",config
)
      console.log(response.data)
  }
  catch(error){ 
    console.log(error)

 }
  }
  fetchData();
```

this is my middleware which cannot access cookie or header both:

```
     export const verifyJWT = asyncHandler(async(req,res,next)=>{
     try{
    const token = req.cookies?.accessToken || req.headers["Authorization"]?.replace("Bearer",                     "")

    console.log(token);
    if(!token){
        throw new ApiError(401 , "No TOken ")
    }
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token , process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
     const user = await User.findById(decodedToken?._id).select("-password -refreshToken")
     if(!user){
        throw new ApiError(401 , "Invalid Access Token")
     }
     req.user = user;
     next();
}
catch(error){
    throw new ApiError(401 , error?.message || "Invalid access token")
}
           })
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.